# Java generating a Blanks String

Tags: java

is there a more efficient way to generate a String full of blanks with a customizable size like the following:

```
private String getBlanks (int numberOfBlanks)
    {
        String theBlanks = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlanks; i++)
        {
            theBlanks = theBlanks + " ";
        }
        return theBlanks;
    }
```

Perhaps with a `StringBuilder` or any other type?

**EDIT:** Since we have [Appache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) the most convinient way of doing is through the use of [String Utils - leftPad](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), thanks everyone for the answers!

Thanks

Comment: Efficient in what way? Coding complexity or execution time? Either way, the question is almost moot in terms of why it would need to be made more efficient.

Comment: I disagree on this one. Though it wouldn't be a horrible crime againt humanity to do it this way, it's not at all tidy to manipulate Strings this way. Amines answer below is (IMO) the way to do it.

Comment: @Tejs referring more to execution time

Comment: On a side note, consider using StrBuilder (part of apache commons lang) instead of StringBuilder.  it is a drop in replacement and the apache folks claim it is better (in general I take them at their word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick hack using [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html):

```
return StringUtils.leftPad("", numberOfBlanks, ' ');
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, you need [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) for this

Comment: We have Appache Commons and I find this way the most efficient :)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe like this:

```
private String getBlanks(int numberOfBlanks) {
       char[] chars = new char[numberOfBlanks];
       Arrays.fill(chars, (char)32);
       return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: Very clever (and some really long phrase so that I can publish it).

Answer (score 5):

With [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/index.html)

```
String blanks = Strings.repeat(" ", numOfblanks);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all - use a `StringBuilder`, and then return `StringBuilder.toString`

Answer (score 2):

```
String getBlankString(int length){
  StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(length);

  for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    sb.append(" ");
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: StringBuffer is thread safe, it's necessary only in specific cases, otherwise it is only adding additional locking.

Answer (score 2):

You want a StringBuilder:

```
private String getBlanks (int numberOfBlanks)
    {
        StringBuilder theBlanks = new StringBuilder(numberOfBlanks);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBlanks; i++) theBlanks.append(" ");
        return theBlanks.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getBlanks (int numberOfBlanks) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.setLength(numberOfBlanks);
    sb.replace(0, numberOfBlanks-1, " ");

    return sb.toString();
}
```